# listView row sizing with respect to its content

Tags: react-native

I want to resize the listView row with respect to its content which is an image and a text,
the image is a remote one, I am reading it from firebase and I am showing it with uri,
when I put a width or a height to the row, the image shows, but what I want to do is to resize the row so that it takes the height of the image.

I found this solution

```
var React = require('react-native');

var {
AppRegistry,
StyleSheet,
View,
Image
} = React;

var TestCmp = React.createClass({
 render: function() {
   return (
     <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
       <Image style={styles.image} source={{uri:   'http://lorempixel.com/200/400/sports/5/![enter image description here][2]'}} />
      </View>
     );
  }
  });

 var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  imageContainer: {
   flex: 1,
   alignItems: 'stretch'
   },
  image: {
    flex: 1
 }
 });

  AppRegistry.registerComponent('RCTTest', () => TestCmp);
```

but it is not working with the listView row

i also tried to give the container which is the listView row:
       flex: 1,
       alignItems: 'stretch',
       left:0,
       right:0,
       height: 500,

and the image:
       flex:1,

but of course the image with have a height of 500, and it will be stretched so some part of it will be invisible.

Comment: Would you be so nice to provide a small RNPlay (https://rnplay.org/) snippet showing the problem? That way other could easier try to solve the problem for you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved!
the save the problem i used Image.getSize and calculated the height with respect to the width of the screen.
but Image.getSize is asynchronous, so what I did is the following:
1-I calculated the width of the screen by importing Dimensions and saved save it in a variable.

```
var widthScreen = Dimensions.get('window').width;
```

2- I added 2 empty arrays in the states: one called 'itemsForListView' and the other is 'items', you will see why in a while.

3- in 'listenForItems' method implemented to read the data from fireBase, I wrote:

```
listenForItems(itemsRef) {
var index= 0; //to track the image
// get children as an array
itemsRef.on('value', (snap) => {
  var items = [];
  snap.forEach((child) => {
     this.setState({
      items: this.state.items.concat([{ //I am adding the elements one by one to the state
       title: child.val().title,
       image: child.val().image,
       year: child.val().year,
       index: index,
       _key: child.key(),
       width: this.state.widthScreen, //give it the width of the screen as a variable
       height:0 //for the moment because I can't calculate it
      }])});
        this.getImageSize(child.val().image, index++);
    });
    });
     }


getImageSize(uri, ind) {
Image.getSize(uri, (width, height) => {
  //calculate the new height with respect to the width of the screen
  this.state.items[ind].height = this.state.widthScreen * height / width;
  this.setState({
    itemsForListView: this.state.itemsForListView.concat([
      this.state.items[ind]
    ])
  });
//feed the listView with the ready image
this.setState({
    dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows( this.state.itemsForListView)
  });
});
 }
```

4- now in the renderRow method of the list view you can use item.width and item.height in order to give the image the desired size.

Comment: Thanks but it's very confusing for me. I wish there's a way to specify "height: AutoSize" (Xamarin-style) or something like that...